# Android looping problem, how to loop properly?

Tags: android, loops

I'm developing my own android application, but there's one problem that i not yet fix.

App screenshot

[image]

It should be just 2 person, ihsan and ridwan. But it's show ridwan 2 times How to avoid this?

This is my code

```
int prev=0;
        for(int x = 0;x<mDataset.size();x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<mDataset.get(x).people.size();y++){
                if((x+y+prev)==position){
                    person = mDataset.get(x).people.get(y);
                    holder.lblFullname.setText(mDataset.get(x).people.get(y).getFullname());
                    holder.lblOrigin.setText(mDataset.get(x).originname);
                    requirements=mDataset.get(x).requirements;
                    uploaded=mDataset.get(x).people.get(y).getUploaded();
                }
            }
            //prev++;
        }
```

Comment: can you please show some more code, please? I cannot understand your question properly.

Comment: How does your data structure look like? Why are there two nested loops? And what's the intention of this `if((x+y+prev)==position)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adapter, there is no need for a loop. You can just set the values like follows.

```
holder.lblFullname.setText(mDataset.get(position).getFullname());
```

This is how I pass values to the TextView through Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AddPresetMessagesListHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.MyMessages.setText(dataList.get(position).getMsg());
    holder.UserName.setText(dataList.get(position).getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
```

Comment: but if i'm not using the loop, there just be 1 value right?

Comment: No, You should set the adapter to the list or recyclerView. Then, you will be able to see the list as per the "dataList.size();" let me know if you need more code on showing list view(RecyclerView).@Nico